# Is there an easy way to rearrange a number in java?

Tags: java, arrays, integer

Basically in a nut shell I want to take a random number say:

```
73524896
```

and I want to us the same number but randomly rearrange it like this:

```
46932857
```

Is there a way I can do this easily in java?

Comment: Sorry, it's just an example. I'll fix it.

Comment: Why in the world are their close votes on this question?

Comment: Is this for a project Euler problem?

Comment: For what reason is this not a real question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will this help you : [Random Numbers - shuffling](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/algorithms/random/random-shuffling.html).

Not a complete code, just a snippet from the link

```
Random rgen = new Random();  // Random number generator
int[] cards = new int[52];  

//--- Initialize the array to the ints 0-51
for (int i=0; i<cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i] = i;
}

//--- Shuffle by exchanging each element randomly
for (int i=0; i<cards.length; i++) {
    int randomPosition = rgen.nextInt(cards.length);
    int temp = cards[i];
    cards[i] = cards[randomPosition];
    cards[randomPosition] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this works great! Thanks. I can accept in 7 minutes.

Comment: As above, a random, but not a perfectly random, shuffle.

Comment: @Neil : Go ahead and please explain what you mean ? Did you visit the link before commenting ?

Comment: I don't need to visit the link, I know a simple counterexample. If there are 3 things to shuffle, then there are 6 shuffles, but your loop generates 27 permutations equally randomly. You therefore can't generate the 6 shuffles equally randomly.

Comment: @Neil : This is not the complete code. Its just a code snippet.

Comment: **@Neil, what a super-awesome explanation.** Did you come up with it or did you hear about it from somewhere?

Comment: @aioobe It's not original, but I can't remember where I saw it, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my favorite solution. (Note that all shufflings are equally probable.)

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int rndInt = rnd.nextInt(10000000);

String[] rndChars = ("" + rndInt).split("(?<=.)");
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(rndChars));
String result = "";
for (String s : rndChars) result += s;
int shuffled = Integer.parseInt(result);

// Print original and shuffled
System.out.println(rndInt);
System.out.println(shuffled);
```

**Sample output:**

```
4769797
9497767
```

Comment: my answer, but with code, and faster.  doubleplus good!

Comment: I answered it already with the link, you provided the code :)

Comment: Can also use Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(chars)); instead of the for loop.

Comment: @Swati, I'm really curious, how?

Comment: Collections.shuffle( ) works for only objects, not primitive types. http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/algorithms/random/random-shuffling.html

Comment: You should use a Fischer-Yates or other random shuffle. This one isn't as random as it could be.

Comment: Hum, it's not? Provided `rnd.nextInt` returns a uniformly random number, each elements new pos should be uniformly distributed, no?

Comment: sigh, my bad. I was looking at Strings :/

Answer (score 1):

```
//generate random number
String number = "73524896";

//put each digit in an element of a list
List<Character> numberList = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (char c : number.toCharArray()){
  numberList.add(c);
}

//shuffle
Collections.shuffle(numberList);

//output
String shuffledNumber = "";
for (Character c : numberList){
  shuffledNumber += c;
}
System.out.println(shuffledNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

turn it into a string, get the character array, then randomize the character array, and turn it back into a string.

that would let you randomize any string, not just numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way to do this is to parse the integer to a String, rearrange the digit in the String then parse it back to integer.

```
public int rearrange(int num){
  StringBuilder asStr = new StringBuilder(num + ""); //convert to string

  inplaceShuffle(asStr);


  return Integer.parseInt(asStr.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) Convert the number to a string

(2) Use a standard [shuffling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Shuffling_algorithms) to shuffle the characters

(3) Convert back to a number

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.shuffle()` takes a list and returns a list, which has a `toArray()`. `Arrays.asList()` takes an array and returns a list. String has a `toCharArray()` and a constructor that accepts a char array. Integer has `toString()` and `valueOf()`

Comment: Incomplete (Arrays.asList won't work on a `char[]`.)  You need a library function (e.g. commons-collections or guava, or roll your own) to do that

Comment: Nuts. You're right, of course. I suppose you could also split using "\\d" instead of getting the char array. That's not very efficient, though... And then I'd have to have a String.join() that doesn't exist instead.